# Git smudge filter

Tags: git

I am trying to setup a filter so that on checkout it will inject some git related information to my file and on commit it will remove this information. I have verified that when I commit the file it is properly cleaned. Also if I delete the file and then do a checkout the file is properly smudged.

My problem is the following. **If I make a change to the file and I commit the change, the smudge filter does not run.** Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to have the smudge filter run on commit? (perhaps by having a commit followed immediately by a checkout?)

Comment: "when I commit the file it is properly cleaned": so the filter does work on commit, yes?. But maybe he does not take into account what has been added to the index...

Comment: The clean filter works on commit and the smudge filter works on checkout. I was wondering if there is a way to have the smudge filter run after I commit so that information in the file that is related to the commit hash etc. is automatically updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A clean/smudge filter is definitely not the place for reliably adding commit based information into a work tree file. The reason - as you've discovered - is that the file won't be touched in operations that don't have to write a new version of the file into the work tree. You can merge or fast-forward many commits without the filter being applied if the given file hasn't been touched by those commits.

You would probably be better off with a template file that can be transformed to an ignored real file with embedded commit information by a build step which uses something like `git rev-parse HEAD` or `git describe` to retrieve the current commit information.